# Delete User Account after x days

Tags: php, mysql

I am saving the users registration date in mysql database in the `signupdate` column and then I add 2 days to that date and save it in the `expiredate` column.

**this all works fine.**

I need to know how I can delete the user account if the `expiredate` date is reached?

I know this can be done using *cron jobs* but I have difficulties to grasp the concept.

here is how I save the expiredate and signupdate in mysql database:

```
$date = date ( 'Y-m-d' );
$newdate = strtotime ( '+2 days' , strtotime ( $date ) ) ;
$newdate = date ( 'Y-m-d' , $newdate );

$stmt = mysqli_prepare(
    $db_conx,
    "INSERT INTO users (expiredate, signupdate) VALUES (?, now())"
);
//after validation, of course
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $newdate);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
if (mysqli_affected_rows($db_conx))
{
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    //update was successful
    $id = mysqli_insert_id($db_conx);
}
```

could someone please guide me on this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are struggling and have cPanel I recommend http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-automate-functions-on-your-website-with-cro.html

Also to get accounts after expire date, get the current date during the cron and then check against there expire date, if todays date is greater than expire date then delete them

Comment: @Ian, no, I am not struggling with cron jobs or cpanel. I am struggling with the mysql function that deletes the user account  once the expiredate is reached.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like:

```
DELETE FROM `users` WHERE `expiredate` < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL X DAY)
```

However, first do a select with this where condition and see if it selects what you expect. I'd then recommend using an `active` field and just disabling the account - that way you can un-delete someone.

Comment: agreed. let me give this a go.

Comment: a quick question, could you please let me know what the X is in the code above?

Comment: X is the number of days, so for instance you said "after x days" - so it's exactly the same as what you meant ;)

Comment: Ah, so lets say i stored 2014-05-13 in expiredate column in mysql database. If i change X to 10, the code above will delete that after 10 days which is on 2014-05-23?

Comment: yes. well, actually it'll delete it on the first second after the end if the 23rd. Along with every other account that falls above those dates

Comment: so if that is the case, then I don't need to save/store the `expiredate` in mysql database as I am already storing the `signupdate` in mysql database! or do I still need to store the expiredate as well? please take a look at the way I store these two `timestamps` in mysql database in the code in my question.

Comment: ah please ignore my last post. i was a bit confused. i got it now.. appreciate it...

Comment: @user3592614 If you're storing them as unix timestamps, wrap `DATE_SUB()` with `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`. And yes, you can just use the signup date.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like, where d is the no. of days

```
DELETE FROM users WHERE DATEDIFF(expiredate,signupdate)>=d
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts to your requirement :

- Write a script to remove user accounts where the expired are is reached.  This can be done in PHP and you can test your script from the command line.
- Run this script on a regular schedule.   This is what you will use cron for.  The cron service runs every minute and reads a file called a crontab.  If there are jobs in the crontab matching the current time they are started. You should search for "cron" to find hundreds of sites describing the format of crontab, for example http://www.unixgeeks.org/security/newbie/unix/cron-1.html

You normally use the command line to edit crontab by running the command `crontab - e`.

Some cheaper hosting providers do not allow you to run cron jobs.  If this is your situation there are alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

If you can create an event on your database, you could do the following:

```
DELIMITER ~
DROP EVENT IF EXISTS clearUsers~
CREATE EVENT clearUsers
ON SCHEDULE
    EVERY 15 MINUTE
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
DO BEGIN
    DELETE EXPIRED USERS;COMMIT;
END~
DELIMITER ;
```

The body can be a stored procedure call or just a query.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-event.html